# PARI:similar function like Integer.parseInt()

Tags: type-conversion, pari-gp

I want to convert the text hello to ascii decimal in PARI/GP. After that I will 
concatenate the values.

I initialize a Vecsmall(hello), after that I run a loop to concatenate the ascii decimal values,
I want to use this concatenated value to * by certain values. The value is now in String type, In Java, there is a Integer.parseInt() to convert the string to int. I wonder if there is a similar function in PARI/GP?

```
v=Vecsmall("hello");'
for (i = 1, length(v), text=Str(text,v[i]););
//is there any similar function like Integer.praseInt(text) in PARI?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval`

```
eval(text)
```

or else a combination of `Vecsmall` and `fromdigits` which is faster:

```
fromdigits(apply(n->n-49, Vec(text)))
```